# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365

I am using the code below to send email using office 365

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("Test@yahoo.com"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("ouremailAddress@ourdomain.com");
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.Body = EmailBody;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USername", "Password");
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg);
```

this code work but once every few days i get an error of
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

i know there the question has been asked more than once, but they are very old Like
[SmtpException - The operation has timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743548/smtpexception-the-operation-has-timed-out)

or

[System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out. error in asp.net send mail code using godaddy hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14828304/system-net-mail-smtpexception-the-operation-has-timed-out-error-in-asp-net-sen)

but some say that it is SSL and port issue, i have tried it with other port and still the same. so any help would be great

---

**More Information**
when i do the debugging i don't get this error
but sending an email is with in Try {} and Catch {}
and if there is error the application send an email to me that is how i know there is issue

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select the wrong language tags (like you did)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry, which tag did i select that it was wrong ??

Comment: You had selected the C language tag, while your code is *probably* C#.

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake, still early morning :D

Comment: Have you tried using a `try...catch` retry logic to see if it just had a 100 seconds waiting time?

Comment: It is sitting with in try and catch, and that is how i know i have an issue, when i run the code there is no issue but if there an error the application send notification to me that is how i know there is issue and i know what is the issue, but it does not say anything regarding 100 seconds waiting time

Comment: how many mails are you sending? Are you being blocked as a spammer?

Comment: these are system emails, 4 to 10  once every hour, and this is company office365 smtp,

Comment: I have same error. I am using port 25 for smtp on office365, but this error seems to be frequent(sometimes i do send a mail without any error). also sometimes i get 'Thread was being aborted' error. Does changing SMTP Timeout help in this scenario as it is default to 100 seconds?